# tspan is always hidden on FF

Tags: d3.js, svg

I have a d3 code [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lb55ukar/124/). `Upper text here` is visible in all browser except FF.

Here is the complete code:

```
var data = [2000, 400]; 
var chart = d3.select("#container").append("svg") 
  .attr("class", "chart")
  .attr("width", 800) // bar has a fixed width
  .attr("height", 300)
    .style("padding-top", "20px")

var x = d3.scale.linear() 
  .domain([0, d3.max(data)])
  .range([10, 100]);

chart.selectAll("rect") 
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("y", 18)
  .attr("x", 10)
  .attr("width", function(d){
  return x(d) - 10
  })
  .attr("height", 10)


var text = [0];
var data = ['Upper text here']

chart.selectAll("text") 
  .data(text)
  .enter()
  .append("text")
  .attr("x",x)
  .attr("dy", ".25em") 
  .append('tspan')
  .text('Upper text here')
  .attr('x', x)
  .attr("y", function(_, i) {
    return i === 1 ? 42 : -9;
  })
  .attr('dy', '.35em')
```

Not sure, whats the mistake here.

Comment: Your `text` and `tspan` is sitting inside the 20px padding of the SVG because of your -9 y position.  Looks like chrome is showing it inside the padding, while firefox is not.

Comment: Initially I thought about it, but removing top padding doesn't help. Actually the real issue I guess its with `-9` position.

Comment: The top padding is *saving* you in Chrome.  Yes the issue is the `-9`, set that to `0` and remove the padding,  then you'll notice your word is cut in half consistently in both.

Comment: Yes, I guess the quick way is to move the image using `viewBox`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- In SVG 1.1 the overflow property on `<svg>` elements defaults to hidden.
- In SVG 2 it is proposed that it default to visible.

It seems like Chrome has implemented this proposed SVG 2 change but Firefox probably won't.

You really should draw inside the SVG canvas and not depend on overflow visible as it has a pretty big performance hit since the browser can no longer assume that the maximum SVG canvas bounds are the outer SVG element's height and width.

If you really must draw outside the bounds then simply set overflow explicitly to get consistent cross-browser behaviour e.g.

```
var chart = d3.select("#container").append("svg") 
  .attr("class", "chart")
  .attr("width", 800) // bar has a fixed width
  .attr("height", 300)
  .attr("overflow", "visible")
    .style("padding-top", "20px")
```